# Convert Periodic fraction beetween numeral systems.

Tags: number-systems

I need convert 13.23(2233) (Quaternary) to Hexadecimal
I should convert 13.232233 to Decimal and Decimal convert to Hex? There are quite a lot of calculations on addition of fractions.And then multiplying. Or is there another solution?

Comment: Two quaternary digits give one hexadecimal ($4^2=16$). $13\rightarrow1\cdot4+3=7, 23\rightarrow B, 22\rightarrow A, 33\rightarrow F$.

Comment: When the bases are unrelated you should convert the given periodic fraction to an integer fraction ${p\over q}$, then do longhand division in the other base to find the new (pre)period.